# Best way to change the size of Storyboard for iPhone version compatibility

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, ios-simulator

I have a quick question about **"Changing storyboard's size"** in user interface. Currently I have an existing project with at least 55+ `viewControllers`. Now I have to change every single one from inspector to make it compatible for both iPhone 6 & iPhone 6 plus. Just wondering is there any short cut way to make the change for all `viewControllers` at a time, instead make change with every single one?

**My xcode version: 6.1.1**
**Use Auto Layout check**
**Use Size Classes uncheck**

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: I think your real problem is that you have 55+ view controllers. I suspect that you're using them incorrectly to need so many.

Comment: @ rdelmar, Thanks for commenting. Yes, in a sense it is. That's why I am thinking is there any easy way to do the job. I am only talking about the size of the `viewControllers`, not any design issues. I must have to repositioning & restructure them after changing the size, that's for sure.